# Is it possible to use Inertia form helper for upload files so, that no file input is involved?

Tags: file-upload, vuejs3, inertiajs

WHat I did is, that through drag' drop i took the value of dataTransfer files, and made form files field equal to that:

```
const form = useForm({
    files: [],
});
form.files = e.dataTransfer.files;
```

Is this a valid method, or for some reason it is mandatory to use file input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`e.dataTransfer.files` is a perfectly valid way to access the file list, especially within a drag and drop operation. You're doing it right.

Comment: Thanks Abraham! Helpful.

Comment: as an aside, the inertia docs have a section on how to handle uploads (although it doesn't deal with drag and drop, you should be able to shove the file in manually and the rest of the guide will be relevant although I haven't done that myself, I have used this guide to build a simple file uploader) https://inertiajs.com/file-uploads